# SP online - cannot add custom webPart

Tags: sharepoint-online

I create sandbox webpart in on-premise server and I want to upload in SP online.

When i trying to activate a solution, this is following error:

[image]

How to resolve this problem. Thank you previously..

Comment: Have a look [HERE](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c339513f-1f55-4af7-9e96-18fd2bfbfda4/cannot-activate-sandboxed-solutions-in-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sandbox solution has been deprecated based on [Sandboxed Solutions Deprecation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions/) , and you will need to convert your solution to SharePoint Add-ins, to get started check [SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx) and [Get started creating provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx)

Meanwhile , the following steps was worked before , Try it

- Open your solution via visual studio >
- Right click on your project > Properties  >
- Set `Include Assembly In Package` to **FALSE**

[image]

- Rebuild the solution and try again to upload WSP to SharePoint online.

Comment: Whrere i try to add webpart in my page, web page says: $Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;

Comment: are you talk about Include Assembly In Package steps ? , this was work before based on this thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c339513f-1f55-4af7-9e96-18fd2bfbfda4/cannot-activate-sandboxed-solutions-in-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint ,

Comment: I activate webpart, but where i want to use error is : $Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage

Comment: this mean the solution has been activated but , the issue in activating web part ? right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. Please help me

Comment: what this solution do/have ?  meanwhile as I told you above The sandbox solution has been deprecated so this may be not work , can you convert it to add-in ?

Answer (score -1):

Does your solution contain custom code?

If yes , have a look at this [Technet Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/marios_mo_betta_blog/2016/08/02/sharepoint-online-sandboxed-solutions-disabled/)

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer? If the link breaks it will render useless to future readers

Comment: of course.  @Goshbuy used a custom webpart in his solution, which can contain custom code (C# i guess). Sandbox solution containing custom codes have been deprecated since 2014 and Microsoft decided to disable them since August 2016.

Comment: So, if the webpart is based on C# code, the solution will never be able to be activated. You need to remake the webpart by using client side languages ( Html / Javascrit ...)

Comment: You can edit your answer (click the edit button below your answer), and put this information there.